# Why would a C# method return an abstract class?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a library and one which returns a response object.  I like to look at a few examples e.g. how MSFT does this.

I looked at Azure BlobClient delete method which returns Azure.Response() object which itself is marked as abstract yet I can use the Response object like any instantiated object.

```
var response = blobClient.Delete(...)
if(response.Status ==206)
{
    etc
```

I don't understand the implementation - this delete method (which is virtual on the BlobClientBase base class but does not appear to be overridden by BlobClient) returns an abstract class.

**Q:** how could it have been instantiated so that I use that directly?  Likely I'm missing a bit of OO theory here - thanks in advance for any insight.

From BlobClientBase metadata...

```
public class BlobBaseClient        
{
...
public virtual Response Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption snapshotsOption = DeleteSnapshotsOption.None, BlobRequestConditions conditions = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

From Azure.Storage.Blobs metadata...

```
public class BlobClient : BlobBaseClient
```

The definition of Response is below,  I assume abstract means Response as it stands is missing some implementation (e.g. its own abstract properties and methods).

From Azure.Core metadata....

```
public abstract class Response : IDisposable
{
    protected Response();

    public abstract int Status { get; }
    public abstract string ReasonPhrase { get; }
    public abstract Stream? ContentStream { get; set; }
    public abstract string ClientRequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual ResponseHeaders Headers { get; }
    public static Response<T> FromValue<T>(T value, Response response);
    public abstract void Dispose();
    public override string ToString();
    protected internal abstract bool ContainsHeader(string name);
    protected internal abstract IEnumerable<HttpHeader> EnumerateHeaders();
    protected internal abstract bool TryGetHeader(string name, [NotNullWhen(true)] out string? value);
    protected internal abstract bool TryGetHeaderValues(string name, [NotNullWhen(true)] out IEnumerable<string>? values);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why they picked the abstract class instead of an interface? (Assuming you understand what abstract classes are...)

Comment: yes - and original question was how it works with returning an abstract class as a return value yet I can use it like a concrete instance of a class.  I think @adjan's point that the return type of the method is not the same as the returned object instance the method returns and this concept points me in the right direction (i.e. learn a little more about those types).  Your question is then also pertinent - why not return an interface (not arguing with the designer but interested what led to that design choice).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The abstract class `Response` is the return type of the method, not the type of the returned instance. You can define an abstract class as the return type, but what you need to return is a concrete implementation that is inheriting from the abstract class.

```
abstract class Abstract {}

class Concrete : Abstract {}

Abstract MyMethod() {
   return new Concrete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  to map it onto my situation.  I'd have an abstract class Response separate from the class hierarchy.  Say I have an abstract class SomethingBase.  The base has a method "abstract Response Do()".  Then I have a concrete class Something : SomethingBase.    Is it inside method Do() on the base that I create a concrete instance of Response?

Answer (score -6):

it occurs to me that when receiving an abstract class you could implement your own response, overwriting the existing methods or inheriting them as well. If it was an interface instead of an abstract class, you wouldn't be able to get the result after executing the delete. Lucky

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.response?view=azure-dotnet#properties

Comment: Thanks but this was more a question of the design of the MSFT class structure vs a work around for how to use an abstract result.